Old black and white movie about a scientist who could talk to animals
I am looking for this old movie I watched when I was a kid in the 70's.
The movie looks like it was done in the 30's or 40'.
It was dubbed in French but I think it was from the USA.
It was about a scientist who could talk to animals.
He was in court (not sure the reason why) and to prove to the judge that he could talk to animals they called the judge's dog and he asked him what the judge ate for dinner. The dog gave a precise answer.
I can also remember that he was stranded in an island and at the end in order to go back he constructed a flying machine with the help of the inhabitants of the island and the machine had the shape of a butterfly.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

This looks like the 1967 movie Dr. Dolittle. It's a color movie though.
Some excerpts copied from the wiki entry:

Fishermen mistake the seal for a woman, and have Doctor Dolittle arrested on a charge of murder. General Bellowes is the magistrate in his case, but Dolittle proves he can converse with animals by talking with Bellowes' dog. Though Dolittle is acquitted, the vindictive judge sentences him to a lunatic asylum. Dolittle's animal friends rescue him, and he, Matthew, Tommy, Polynesia, Chee-Chee and Jip set sail in search of the legendary Great Pink Sea Snail. Emma stows away, seeking adventure. They randomly choose their destination: Sea-Star Island, a floating island currently in the Atlantic Ocean.

And later, at the end:

Dolittle cannot go back because he is still a wanted man. Furthermore, he wishes to investigate the natives' stories of another creature, the Giant Lunar Moth. After his friends leave, Dolittle realizes painfully that he has feelings for Emma. Sophie the seal arrives, accompanied by her husband. They bring a message: the animals of England have gone on strike to protest his sentence, and Bellowes has agreed to pardon him. Dolittle and the islanders construct a saddle for the Giant Lunar Moth, and Dolittle flies back to England.

